# net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) wordpress enqueue scripts

Tags: wordpress

```
function add_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'rtlcss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css', array());
wp_enqueue_style( 'test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/test.css', array());
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_styles');
```

net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) when enqueuing test.css  while enqueuing rtl.css does not get any errors although, the two files [rtl.css, test.css] are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

If everything else is set up correctly, the only thing that it could be (based on the information we have) is that the handle ('test') is not unique. Try changing the handle name.